# Draw a graph of periodic extension of a piecewise given function

Tags: periodic-functions, even-and-odd-functions

Let $f(t)$ be a function given as follows:
\begin{equation*}
f(t)=\begin{cases}
          1 \quad &\text{if} \, x \in [0,1) \\
          2 \quad &\text{if} \, x \in [1,2) \\
     \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Draw the graph of the odd extension of the previous function with period $4$ over the interval $(-4,4)$?
How to go ahead with such a function and draw it?

Comment: If it's odd, then you should know what it is if $x\in(-1,0]$ and if $x\in(-2,-1]$

Comment: If $f$ is odd, we need $f(0)=0$, not $1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner The problem is how to plot after periodic extension and values for each interval.

Answer (score 0):

Given the piecewise function, you can graph the function from [0,2) (I assume you've already done that.) Then it tells you that the graph is odd, meaning it is symmetric around the origin. This tells you that f(t)= -1 if x∈[−1,0) and f(t)= -2 if ∈[−2,−1). Now you want to extend the periodic function from (-4,4). It is given that the periodic function has a period of 4. We have already graphed from [-2,2) so you can determine how the graph looks from [2,4) and (-4,2). f(t)= -2 if x∈[2,3), f(t)= -1 if ∈[3,4), f(t)= 2 if x∈[−3,-2), and f(t)= 1 if ∈(−4,-3). Sorry if this is hard to read, I'm also a little unsure about the interval notation I used.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think you meant $(-1,0]$ and $(-2,1]$.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial.

Comment: But wouldn't there be overlap at x=0?

Comment: Yes; actually, an odd function must be $0$ at $0$